# Django authenticate() don't work after first logout

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

If I create new user from the page login after submit, if it's all ok, I do automatic login with `login(request,user)` and rederect user in home page. In this case script works. But if I do logout and subsequently login, `authenticate()` return `None` and the authentication fails.

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


class User(AbstractUser):
    pass


class Email(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="emails")
    sender = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="emails_sent")
    recipients = models.ManyToManyField("User", related_name="emails_received")
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField(blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    archived = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def serialize(self):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "sender": self.sender.email,
            "recipients": [user.email for user in self.recipients.all()],
            "subject": self.subject,
            "body": self.body,
            "timestamp": self.timestamp.strftime("%b %d %Y, %I:%M %p"),
            "read": self.read,
            "archived": self.archived
        }
```

register views

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.POST["email"]

        # Ensure password matches confirmation
        password = request.POST["password"]
        confirmation = request.POST["confirmation"]
        if password != confirmation:
            return render(request, "mail/register.html", {
                "message": "Passwords must match."
            })

        # Attempt to create new user
        try:
            user = User.objects.create_user(email, email, password)
            user.save()
        except IntegrityError as e:
            print(e)
            return render(request, "mail/register.html", {
                "message": "Email address already taken."
            })
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
    else:
        return render(request, "mail/register.html")
```

login views

```
import json
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, render
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

from .models import User, Email

def login_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":

        # Attempt to sign user in
        email = request.POST["email"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        user = authenticate(request, user=email, password=password)

        # Check if authentication successful
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
        else:
            return render(request, "mail/login.html", {
                "message": "Invalid email and/or password"})
    else:
        return render(request, "mail/login.html")
```

Comment: `authenticate(request, user=email, password=password)` you pass the email as a keyword argument `user`, have you implemented a custom backend for authentication that accepts those arguments? Most likely you wanted to write `authenticate(request, username=email, password=password)`

Comment: you are right. now works. thanks